# BeautifulSoup - Why am I getting an empty list as a result?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Why does my code result in an empty list? It's as if the page is too big and it doesn't parse it all... could it be the case?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/nitroparkour')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')
doc = soup.findAll("a", id="video-title")
print(doc)
```

Comment: There are no elements with `id="video-title"`

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the page then "view page source" you will find the `html` of the website, try and search for any of the titles of the videos ex. "Super Mario Maker", you will find them stored on a JSON inside `script` tag in the HTML.

then why do you see the videos inside `a` tag with `id="video-title"` in the page when you "inspect element" using the "dev-tools"?

that's because youtube uses javascript to render the site.

---

here is how to capture that JSON, you will need to explore it and figure which data you need.

```py
import requests, json, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/nitroparkour')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')

unparsed_js = soup.find(string=re.compile('var ytInitialData ='))

js = json.loads(unparsed_js.replace('var ytInitialData = ', '').rstrip(';'))
```

Comment: if you feel that this has satisfactorily answered your question, you may select it as the answer by clicking the check mark ✓. Doing so will gain you 2 reputation.